# WordPress version update for security purposes

Tags: php, wordpress

Our developed website's uses WordPress as our CMS, but the problem is, the WordPress we are using are outdated (old version) our IT Department told us to update the WordPress we are using to avoid security issues.

My question is, if we update the version of the WordPress we are using, is it possible that we can get error from the back-end? (PHP code)

We are planning to try it in the localhost before we update it live.

Comment: You may have issues with old or custom plugins, themes, and ...most important things you have to check the requirements for the last Wordpress version that is: PHP version 7.3+, MySQL 5.6+ or MariaDB 10.0+

Comment: WordPress **doesn't** require PHP 7.3+ (yet). The latest version of WordPress (that's 5.0.3 at the time of writing) can be run under PHP 5.2.0 (or greater) and MySQL 5.0 (or greater) (see [WordPress > About > Requirements](https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/) for more details). Of course, running WordPress with PHP 7 is recommended as it's faster and more secure than older PHP versions.

Comment: Why not just upgrade your localhost version and try it? Keep an eye on your local error logs to see if the upgrade worked.